# Powershell - how do I edit an existing property in a custom object

Tags: powershell, edit, psobject

I looking for way how update noteproperty in existing psobject, for example I have system.array of psobjects ($a):

```
Group                                Assigment
-----                                ---------
Group1                               Home
Group2                               Office
```

Question is how update 'Home' to something other.

$a | gm:

```
TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
Assigment   NoteProperty System.String Assigment=Office
Group       NoteProperty System.String Group=Group1
```

$a.GetType():

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Thank you for future help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not really clear what is your problem : select the good object or update it's value ?

```
$col=@() 
$props=@{"group"="group1";"assignment"="home"}
$col += new-object pscustomobject -property $props
$props2=@{"group"="group2";"assignment"="office"}
$col += new-object pscustomobject -property $props2

#select object with home assignment
$rec=$col | where {$_.assignment -eq "home"}
#replace the value
$rec.assignment="elsewhere"

#display collection with updated value
$col
```

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I need (update Value 'Home' to 'Elsewhere'). It working, but I totally don't know why. You updated variable $col (to 'elsewhere') but change was written to $rec array. Can you quick explain why? There is some inner relation.

Comment: $rec is a subset of the collection (all records where assignment is set to home). Modifying this subset will indeed modify the whole collection

Comment: Thank you, so $rec is another reference to same object? Not copy of object. Like references to objects in heap in C#. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this works if $rec returns more than one record, though.
For example:

```
$rec = $col | where {$_.assignment -ne $null}
$rec.assignment = "elsewhere"
```

In theory that should set every individual record's assignment to "elsewhere" but it really just returns an error that the property "assignment" cannot be found on this object.  I think for this to really work you'd need:

```
$recs = $col | where {$_.assignment -ne $null}
foreach ($r in $recs) {
 $r.assignment="elsewhere"
}
```

Unless there's a way to set a value to every record in a given array, which I freely admit there may be.